# Is it safe to install ActiveScriptRuby on Windows XP with 'standard' Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, windows

I'm using `ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]`. Is it safe to install [ActiveScriptRuby](http://www.geocities.co.jp/SiliconValley-PaloAlto/9251/ruby/main.html) (based on 1.8.7)?

Update (after Luis Lavena's kind encouragement):

I successfully installed ActiveScriptRuby and pik. Evidence:

```
--------------------- PATH
C:\Ruby192\bin
C:\WINDOWS\system32
...
--------------------- pik ls
  187: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i386-mswin32]
* 192: ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]
--------------------- ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]

RUBY C:\Documents and Settings\eh
    cscript m:\lib\kurs0705\xpl\xplmssc.vbs /xf:showLanguages
    xplmssc.vbs - xplore microsoft script control
    ...
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    VBScript 5.7.16599 * cscript 5.7 * WIN XP * WINXPSP3 * eh * 5/12/2011 7:58:30 PM
    ===============================================================================
    showLanguages - show languages
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -------- VBScript
     Expr: 47+11 => 58
     Yes, we can print (WScript.Echo).
    ...
    -------- RubyScript
     Expr: 47+11 => 58
     Yes, we can print (puts).
    ...
    xplmssc.vbs: Erfolgreich beendet. (0) [ 0.42969 secs ]

RUBY C:\Documents and Settings\eh
    pik use 187

RUBY C:\Documents and Settings\eh
    papa
    C:\Program Files\ruby-1.8\bin
    C:\WINDOWS\system32
    ...

RUBY C:\Documents and Settings\eh
    ruby -v
    ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i386-mswin32]
```

So all looks well now. Thanks a lot, Luis!

Comment: Why don't you just try it and report any errors you might see? It probably won't blow up, so it's safe.

Comment: @:kizzx2: because I'm a coward and hope that someone did this experiment and is kind enough to share the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long you don't install both versions of Ruby on the same directory, things are safe.

ActiveScriptRuby and RubyInstaller are not compatible each other, excluding for a second they are different version of Ruby, they use a different compiler toolchain.

If you installed RubyInstaller 1.9.2 into `C:\Ruby192`, then you can safely install ASR into other folder.

You can use an utility named `pik` to manage multiple versions of Ruby on Windows:

https://github.com/vertiginous/pik